# AD users unable to access Samba Share

Tags: samba, active-directory, sssd

I have a RHEL 7.6 server joined to AD using `sssd` and `realm`. I am able to SSH into the Linux servers as AD users, but the same users are unable to access the Samba share configured in the server. When I try to access the share from Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, it keeps prompting me for the password.

This is how I configured `smb.conf`:

```
client signing =yes
client use spnego =yes
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
###ntlm auth =yes
### template homedir = /home/%U
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * :  range = 10000-199999
idmap config DOMAIN: backend = sss
idmap config DOMAIN : range = 200000-2147483647
```

Please check and let me know how I can let AD users to access the shared directories.

Comment: What do the relevant parts of the Samba logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using sssd.
From Samba >= 4.8.0, Shares and sssd are incompatible. If you want shares, then you must use winbind.

Comment: Could you please let me know how the configuration would be

Comment: Replace the 'sss' in your smb.conf file with 'rid'. Remove sssd from the machine and install winbind instead, remove 'sss' from all lines in /etc/nsswitch.conf and add 'winbind' to the 'passwd' & 'group' lines. Before I forget, you will also need the red-hat versions of the Debian libnss-winbind, libpam-winbind and libpam-krb5 files.

Comment: Thanks Rowland. It helped :)